# How do you log all garbage collection events in CLR/.Net?

Tags: debugging, garbage-collection, clr

I'm looking for an equivalent of `java -verbose:gc` or any tool or code snippet to get the same information. Ideally, this would be something I could run in an unattended fashion on a service and log everything to a file. My use case is profiling GC-induced latency in a long-running service.

Comment: PerfView from Microsoft might provide this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For noninvasive .NET GC profiling you have few options. You can either use [CLR Memory Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx) or [CLR Memory Event Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162.aspx) or some profiler (SciTech memory profiler has a nice command line tool that allows you to collect CLR profiling data in the production environment - other .NET profiles probably also expose such a feature).

I suppose that **Performance Counters** are the least invasive method, but they don't give you a detailed information on GC working - though you can see how many collections were performed (in each generation) as well as how much time your process spent in GC. To collect this information you may use perfmon, typeperf or Powershell (I once described different ways of using perf counters so you may have a look: http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/diagnosing-applications-using-performance-counters/)

**ETW events** provide much more details on GC inner workings. You can configure the ETW provider manually (using logman or xperf for example) or use an excellent tool [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) (as @Marc pointed in a comment). If you are only interested in GC events, check `GC Only` checkbox in the Collect windows:

[image]

There is a great episode of Defrag Tools dedicated to CLR GC profiling (part 4): http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-36-CLR-GC-Part-4, I also recommend you checking the other parts as well as reading the PerfView documentation. PerfView is a really powerful tool and it even allows you to analyse .NET Heap and compare memory snapshots.

The last option (that is using **a memory profiler**) is probably the most invasive of the three methods, but sometimes might give you even more details on GC heaps (especially when you would like to analyse the objects graphs). I can't think of any good free GC Memory Profiler so probably you will need to pay to get one of those tools. I have some experience with SciTech Memory Profiler (it's pretty good and, as I mentioned earlier, they have [a command line client](http://memprofiler.com/nmpcore.aspx) that allows you to collect data on production). I also tried Visual Studio Memory profile - it's not bad but less powerfull than the SciTech one - and finally JetBrains and RedGate also sell memory profilers which are well know among .NET developers and probably comparable to SciTech.

Comment: I'm quite new to Windows development so this is really useful information!